# Pass variables inside render to outside?

Tags: shopify, liquid

It seems impossible for the outside caller to use any variable inside a `render`? Take this for example:

test.liquid:

```
{% assign test_xyz = '123abc' %}
```

template.liquid:

```
{% render 'test' %}
{{ test_xyz }}
```

Which outputs nothing.

How can the outside use variables inside `render`? Can `render` return anything? Or is it not possible in Shopify any more since `include` has been deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can the outside use variables inside render?

It can't. That would violate encapsulation. When a partial template is rendered, the code inside it can’t access its parent’s variables and its variables won’t be accessible by its parent. This encapsulation makes partials easier to understand and maintain.

> Can render return anything?

Unfortunately not. But maybe we are doing a mistake by thinking about `render` tag as of a `function` (which doesn't exist). My guess is that Shopify is trying its best to simplify liquid as much as possible, thus making server side rendering faster.

> Or is it not possible in Shopify any more since include has been deprecated?

`include` tag is deprecated already for around 3 years already and it still can be used as there are no plans for removing it (at least I could not find any announcement stating that). It definitely affects the publishing process though, if you'd like to sell your theme in market place. The best option is to rethink the theme structure I guess.

Comment: I tried to use include but the gives error of "Liquid error (facets line xxxx): include usage is not allowed in this context". Any idea how I can use it?

Comment: @datasn.io have you tried to mix `render` and `include` tags or you got this error by CLI? Maybe editing in theme editor helps to overcome this problem?